# How to wrap multiple HTML strings with tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a new to coding and trying to wrap a large list of strings with HTML tags. After searching, I already found a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075474/regex-to-wrap-strings-with-html-tags) here but I've tried it in VS Code and it seems to be not working for me. Probably I'm doing something wrong.

To clarify it further, I'm trying to wrap a large list of strings with HTML tags.

```
Elina Arnwine
Freddie Cane
Melia Pittenger
Nobuko Grove
.....
```

to

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Elina Arnwine</a></li>
....
```

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regex is completely wrong for this. Which language are you using? javascript?

Comment: yes javascript.

Comment: If I'm not using appropriate tags for the question, kindly please edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're using javascript which makes it really simple to do this by mapping over the list and creating the elemnts:

```js
const names = [
  'Elina Arnwine',
  'Freddie Cane',
  'Melia Pittenger',
  'Nobuko Grove'
  ];
  
function createLI(name) {
  const el = document.createElement('li');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  el.className = 'nav-item';
  a.className = 'nav-link text-small pb-0';
  a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
  el.appendChild(a);
  document.getElementById('ul').appendChild(el);
}

names.map(createLI);
```

```html
<ul id='ul'></ul>
```

Or you could use a template

```js
const names = [
  'Elina Arnwine',
  'Freddie Cane',
  'Melia Pittenger',
  'Nobuko Grove'
];
  

function manTemplate(name) {
  const tmp = document.getElementById('li-template');
  const clone = document.importNode(tmp.content, true);
  clone.querySelector('a').innerText = name;
  document.getElementById('ul').appendChild(clone);
}

names.map(manTemplate);
```

```html
<template id="li-template">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 "></a></li>
</template>

<ul id='ul'></ul>
```